# Is there a better way to write a query for deleting records based on sub queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, timeout

I have this query:

```
DELETE from MailingListTable where Md5Hash in (
   SELECT
      dbo.ListItems.Md5Hash
   FROM dbo.Lists
   INNER JOIN dbo.ListItems ON dbo.Lists.Id = dbo.ListItems.ListId
   where dbo.Lists.IsGlobal = 1
 )
```

The MailingListTable is built dynamically from multiple lists. I then run the above query to remove any list items that are in a global remove list.

It's not horrible on small sets, but larger sets it can take almost 5 to 8 minutes (based on some tests I did). I am curious if there is a better way to write this. I don't believe I can use joins with a delete statement. So that is why I opted for the sub query.

I also tried using `EXISTS`, but that was much slower. Would it be better to use `common-table expressions` since I am using SQL Server 2008?

Comment: You can use `select distinct dbo.ListItems.Md5Hash` besides that you can make sure that there's a key on the MailingListTable's Md5Hash column.

Comment: @user814064, on a small set I tested I went from 40s down to 30s using your suggestions. The MD5Hash was already keyed.

Comment: Are you deleting a large percentage of the records? If so, maybe you should select the records you're keeping into a new table. Otherwise why do you have to do a delete at all? Just create a FilteredMailingListTableView on the table that returns the records you want and use that. The best way to speed something up, is not to do it.

Comment: @user814064 I'm not sure I could buy into that technique of just hiding the rows you meant to delete. Eventually you may have billions of "deleted" rows and 100 actual rows. That's probably not good.

Comment: From reading the question: It's a temporary table that's built dynamically.

Comment: @user814064 from reading your comment I have no idea how you came to such a conclusion.

Comment: @user814064, it is not a temporary table, I only stated it is built dynamically. The table is actually created. Unless you were talking about something else.

Comment: @user814064 do you think this table is built every hour?

Comment: I have no idea. The best optimization will come from understanding the process from beginning to end. Can things be added to the global list , if so the delete needs to run every time you use the list. Can things be removed from the global list, if so the delete is an error. I don't assume that this is an SQL problem -- instead a process improvement problem. Hence my asking questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I presume it takes a long time because (a) you're deleting millions of rows and (b) you are treating your log like a revolving door. This isn't going to magically go from 5-8 minutes to 5 seconds because you use EXISTS instead of IN or change a subquery to a CTE or using a JOIN. Go ahead and try it, I bet it is no better:

```
DELETE ml 
  FROM dbo.MailingListTable AS ml
  INNER JOIN dbo.ListItems AS li
  ON ml.Md4Hash = li.Md5Hash
  INNER JOIN dbo.Lists AS l
  ON l.Id = li.ListId 
  WHERE l.IsGlobal = 1;
```

The problem is almost certainly the I/O involved with performing the `DELETE`, not the method used to identify the rows to delete. I bet a `SELECT` using the exact same data and without changing index structure etc. and no matter the isolation level does *NOT* take 5-8 minutes.

So, how to fix?

First, make sure that your log is tuned to handle transactions of that size.

- Pre-size the log so that it doesn't ever have to grow during such an operation, perhaps to double whatever the largest size you've seen it. The exact ideal size is not something someone on Stack Overflow is going to be able to tell you.
- Make sure auto-growth is not set to silly defaults like 10% or 1MB. Autogrow should be a fallback but, when you need it, it should happen exactly once, not multiple times to cover any specific activity. So make sure it is a fixed size (making the size + duration predictable) and that the size is reasonable (so that it only happens once). What is reasonable? No idea - too many "it depends."
- Disable any jobs that shrink the log - permanently. Deal with
  out-of-control log on a case-by-case basis instead of "preventing"
  log growth by repeatedly shrinking the log file.

Next, consider changing your query to batch those deletes into chunks. You can play around with the `TOP (?)` parameter based on how many rows lead to what kind of duration of transaction (there is no magic formula for this, even if we did have a lot more information).

```
CREATE TABLE #x
(
  Md5Hash SOME_DATA_TYPE_I_DO_NOT_KNOW PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT #x SELECT DISTINCT li.Md5Hash
  FROM dbo.ListItems AS li
  INNER JOIN dbo.Lists AS l
  ON l.Id = li.ListId 
  WHERE l.IsGlobal = 1;

DECLARE @p TABLE(p INT SOME_DATA_TYPE_I_DO_NOT_KNOW PRIMARY KEY);

SELECT @rc = 1;

WHILE @rc > 0
BEGIN
  DELETE @p;

  DELETE TOP (?)  
    OUTPUT deleted.Md5Hash INTO @p
    FROM #x;

  SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT;

  BEGIN TRANSACTION;    

    DELETE ml FROM dbo.MailingListTable AS ml
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @p WHERE Md5Hash = ml.Md5Hash);

  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
  -- to minimize log impact you may want to CHECKPOINT
  -- or backup the log here, every loop or every N loops
END
```

This may extend the total amount of time that the operation takes (especially if you backup or checkpoint on each loop, or add an artificial delay using `WAITFOR`, or both), but should allow other transactions to sneak in between chunks, waiting for shorter transactions instead of the whole process. Also, because you are having less individual impact to the log, it may actually end up finishing a lot faster. But I have to assume that the problem isn't that it takes 5-8 minutes, it's probably that it takes 5-8 minutes *and* blocks. This should alleviate that considerably (and if it does, why do you care how long it takes?).

[I wrote a lot more about this technique here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes).

Comment: I would add to this otherwise excellent answer, that you might also check to see if you have a delete trigger that is doing row-by-row processing instead of a set-based process. I've fixed a few of those.

Comment: @HLGEM yes, that's an excellent point that I didn't consider. Even set-based triggers might have trickle-down effects.